# Timed suspension review bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Since [Sachin Shekhar](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/3303/sachin-shekhar) got a timed suspension, most of his answers have appeared in the [late answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/7996) review section.

Is this by design, or is it some type of bug?

Comment: Not **all**, I don't think. But an awful lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Fixed!  See the new answer on the below Meta post.

It's because he has 1 rep temporarily: [Bug in 'Late Answers' Review Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78721/154510)

I think this is an unintended sideffect?  Or at least a confusing way to have this work.

Comment: Should be reported then...

Comment: @TheAndroNerd That's what your post is :P

Comment: but you can talk to those that can fix it, as far as I am aware? Maybe I read it wrong ;) Nether mind.

Comment: @TheAndroNerd I guess, but anyone can really.  In any case for bugs that aren't urgent I believe posting on Meta is the way to go, they'll see this at some point.

Comment: @Matthew: I noticed that the sudden visibility in the queue led to a big review-mania for his answers. Probably giving 0.5k rep or more (my guess). Is this OK or should this be reverted?

Comment: @ce4 I don't think so, but that's probably a reason why this shouldn't happen.